# How to update a dataframe, from another dataframe with duplicates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Trying to update a column in df1 to df2 based on another value in df1.

df1:

```
# Create DataFrame
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'unique_value': ['xyz123', 'eff987', 'efg125', 'xyz123', 'eff987']})

# Assign ID column (no duplicates)
df1['ID'] = pd.factorize(df1['unique_value'])[0] + 1000

# Call df1
df1

    unique_value    ID
0   xyz123          1000
1   eff987          1001
2   efg125          1002
3   xyz123          1000
4   eff987          1001
```

df2:

```
# Create DataFrame
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'unique_value': ['xyz123', 'eff987', 'efg125', 'xyz123']})

# Call df2
df2

    unique_value
0   xyz123
1   eff987
2   efg125
3   xyz123
```

Desired output for df2:

```
    unique_value      ID
0   xyz123            1000
1   eff987            1001
2   efg125            1002
3   xyz123            1000
```

Can we use a type of table join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use [`.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

  - If the duplicates aren't dropped, the resulting dataframe will have multiple rows, for each `'unique_value'`.
- [SO: pandas merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)
- [pandas User Guide: Merge, join, concatenate and compare](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'unique_value': ['xyz123', 'eff987', 'efg125', 'xyz123', 'eff987'], 'ID': [1000, 1001, 1002, 1000, 1001]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'unique_value': ['xyz123', 'eff987', 'efg125', 'xyz123']})

# merge df2 and df1, while dropping duplicates from df1
df2 = df2.merge(df1.drop_duplicates(), on='unique_value', how='left')

# df2
  unique_value    ID
0       xyz123  1000
1       eff987  1001
2       efg125  1002
3       xyz123  1000
```

### Without dropping duplicates

```py
df2 = df2.merge(df1, on='unique_value', how='left')

# df2
  unique_value    ID
0       xyz123  1000
1       xyz123  1000
2       eff987  1001
3       eff987  1001
4       efg125  1002
5       xyz123  1000
6       xyz123  1000
```